# OTRS 3.3 - Show a dynamic content in text using dynamic field

Tags: otrs

I want to show a "recipient address" in ticket overview small using dynamic field but not able to understand what should be the "Name" in dynamic field as it is not static it will be dynamic depending on the articles?

Comment: You'll need to post some code.

Comment: But i guess in otrs it can be done from the interface

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what I think you want to do:**

You're trying to add a dynamic field that can be filled with a recipient address which is show in the TicketOverviewSmall Template.

**Here's how you can do that**

1. Read the chapter about Dynamic Fields in the [Admin Manual](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.3/en/html/dynamicfields.html#dynamicfields-configuration) and pay attention to Example 4.26
2. Add a dynamic text field in the ticket scope

   - **Name:** Unique Name for this field, only letters and numbers allowed - e.g. RecipientAddress
   - **Label:** The name that will be displayed for this dynamic field - e.g. Recipient Address
   - **Type:** Text
   - **Field Order:** Shouldn't really matter in your case, pick a high number
   - **Validity:** Set it to valid for the field to be displayed
3. Add the dynamic field to the TicketOverviewSmall Template in the Sysconfig, see Example 4.26 from the Documentation above

Comment: Just to be sure: You are trying to show a dynamic field with a **new** value and **not the recipient of the ticket or an article** in the overview, correct?

Comment: I would like to show the recipient  of an article in dynamic field

Comment: This isn't something you would use dynamic fields for. Those are for adding additional information to tickets or articles. The recipient of an article is part of that article's basic information.